# Sphinx index.rst inside directory

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The path to the master doc of a Sphinx build can be specified in `conf.py`. However, this directory path is reflected in the generated HTML, and shows for example in Read The Docs as a missing index. I'd like to use this alternative path to structure my project cleanly - to have configuration at the top level and documentation inside `src`, but have the build essentially get rid of it.

So here's what I had previously:

```
docs
    conf.py
    index.rst
    things
        doc1.rst
        doc2.rst
```

This works, but when lots of files are added to the top level, it gets messy with Sphinx's makefiles etc. I'd like to have this instead:

```
docs
    conf.py
    src
        index.rst
        things
            doc1.rst
            doc2.rst
```

Which builds, but `index.html` is in `build/html/src` instead of `build/html`. I was surprised to find no information on this, other than the fact that `master_doc` in `conf.py` controls the location and name of the main file. How could I get my documentation to be built to `build/html`?

Comment: Specify the output directory on the command line via [`sphinx-build [options] <sourcedir> <outputdir> [filenames …]`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html).

Comment: @StevePiercy That doesn't work. The issue remains regardless of the *target* directory. I want `src` out of the structure, not to move the whole build. Or maybe I missed some option.

Comment: I have no idea what a "target" directory is.

Comment: @StevePiercy Output directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for specifying the location of the configuration file: `-c`.

```
# conf.py
master_doc = 'index'

# structure
docs
    conf.py
    src
        index.rst
        ...
```

Then run `sphinx-build -b html -c . src build/html`. However, this solution indeed needs control over the build command, which is not available in Read The Docs. And it seems that `-c` doesn't work in Sphinx's own makefiles either (with `-M` instead of `-b`).

Comment: That last bit--"And it seems that `-c` doesn't work in Sphinx's own makefiles either (with `-M` instead of `-b`)"--does not seem to be true for me. I was able to get this to work in the makefile with `-M` just fine. I added `-c .` to `SPHINXOPTS` and changed `SOURCEDIR` to `src/` in the Makefile.